# No bootable device during Windows 11 failed upgrade on a Windows / Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Before the crash I had a Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 dual boot on the same SSDSCKKW480H6 Intel 480GB hard drive.

I intended to make a Windows bootable recovery image and then wipe everything and go single boot Ubuntu, however I had some Windows updates, saw I could upgrade to Windows 11, and tried that.  During the Windows 11 download/upgrade, I got a blue screen error and the computer rebooted, except I got a `no bootable device found` error message.

I would be happy losing all of the data on both Windows and Linux partitions as long as I could get the use of my SSD back.

The BIOS menu, or at least the only menu I can access by mashing F1 through F12 keys is a setup GUI where I can tweak the boot order and the clock speed, however the actual SSD does not show up as anything to boot from.

I booted from a live USB, and tried Boot-Repair (the suggested repair is "the default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot), however the Boot-Repair text file does indicate that Windows is installed in the MBR of `/dev/sdc`.

sdc1:

- all blank

sdc2:

- file system ext4
- rest blank

sda:

- file system iso9660
- boot sector type grub2 vXX
- boot sector info: grub2 vXX is installed in the boot sector of sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at this location.

Mounting failed: mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.

Full Boot-Repair report:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wdWDN7NKK4/

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

No OS to fix.
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.





============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: L1.05P(5.12) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - This system doesn't support Secure Boot.
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdc2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdc2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdc2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 15.12 GiB, 16231956480 bytes, 31703040 sectors
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1       64  7465119  7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
sda2  7465120  7473615     8496  4.1M EFI System
sda3  7473616  7474215      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  7475200 31702976 24227777 11.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 74A58314-ACFD-4B32-B357-400F24D09F3F
       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdc1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
sdc2  264192 3907028991 3906764800  1.8T Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:16.2GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:USB 2.0 USB Flash Drive:;
1:32.8kB:3822MB:3822MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3822MB:3826MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3826MB:3827MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3827MB:16.2GB:12.4GB:ext4::;
sdc:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z:;
1:17.4kB:134MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:135MB:2000GB:2000GB:ext4:Basic data partition:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda    iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sda1 iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2 vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee ESP                      Appended2
├─sda3                                               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee                          Gap1
└─sda4 ext4     e8a9fd3b-7d0d-45c5-9784-b877f4195665 f0f44455-1658-5843-97f0-a501a790b968 writable                 
sdb                                                                                                                
sdc                                                                                                                
├─sdc1                                               c6f32ebd-1e42-484b-8c2a-57b4265aa05c                          Microsoft reserved partition
└─sdc2 ext4     c4994838-cb9b-4ec7-811e-8088b0e429c1 4b16e550-ad1a-43cb-a262-d3bcf2fb9f44 data1                    Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                              Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-01-15.0/crash] 10.7G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-01-15.0/log]   10.7G   0% /var/log
/dev/sda1                                                         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/sdc2                                                      1.2T  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc2

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________
```

Again, an easy 'wipe everything' command would be a terrific solution at this point although if there is a way of accessing a few recent files on the Linux partition and/or retrieving my Windows license information so I could install Windows again if I needed to, that would be great too.

I do think the root cause if I had to guess is that the Microsoft partition was not GPT which turns out is a requirement for Windows 11, but that's beside the point now.

Comment: If Windows in UEFI mode, the product key is in your UEFI. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-windows-product-key-aaa2bf69-7b2b-9f13-f581-a806abf0a886 You show sda as your live installer flash drive and sdc with two partitions, one ext4. No installs are shown. Is there also a sdb?

Comment: @oldfred: ultimately, I was very lucky- I just restarted my computer after a shutdown rather than attempting to reboot and windows came up!  That let me write down the product key.

Comment: @Nmath: because I got lucky with the reboot, after I got the windows product key, I did exactly that.  100% ubuntu now, thank you.

Comment: @karel:  thank you for the incredible attention to detail you showed in correcting all my capitalization errors as well as improving the overall grammar.